# Should pretty error pages be served with the correct status codes?

Tags: http, html, custom-errors

I noticed that, say, goolge's 404 page returns a 404 status (http://www.google.com/404.html) while github's returns 200 (https://github.com/404.html). Should error pages (even 503s, etc.) always be served with the correct status codes? Or should front end servers intercept them and display 200ed error pages?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Error pages should always be served with the correct status codes.

Comment: Thank you -- any chance you have references?

Comment: @Aaron - besides common sense? I don't know why on earth github would return a 200 OK on a 404 page...

Comment: @Mark Henderson Access any other invalid URL on GitHub and it'll return a 404. 404.html is a real HTML page that's presumably included when a 404 is encountered.

Comment: Note that this can't be done effectively on IIS 7.5: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968018/coldfusion-error-and-iis7-5-error-pages/6618714#6618714

Answer (score 2):

GitHub's 404.html page is returning 200 because you're directly accessing their 404 template.

https://github.com/lollerskates returns a 404 status code, as it should be.

Comment: Ahh yeah, I realized that after I posted. I guess Google doesn't have a file called 404.html... lol.